# Else statement is not working. Getting error: TypeError: markdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, django, cs50

Django code is to create an **Entry Page** where Visiting **/wiki/title**, where **TITLE** is the title of an encyclopedia entry, should render a page that displays the contents of that encyclopedia entry. The view should get the content of the encyclopedia entry by calling the appropriate util function. If an entry is requested that does not exist, the user should be presented with an error page indicating that their requested page was not found.

But if statement is working fine, but else statement is not working. When I am browsing http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/CSS, it should navigate me to that dedicated page. But I am getting an error: markdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'. Please advise how to mitigate this error?

**views.py**

```
from markdown import markdown
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import util

#EntryPage using title
def entry(request, entry):
    #markdowner = markdown()
    entryPage = util.get_entry(entry)
    #Displays the requested entry page, if it exists
    if entryPage is None:
         return render(request, "encyclopedia/nonExistingEntry.html", {
             "entryTitle": entry
         })
        # Title exists, convert md to HTML and return rendered template
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdown().convert(entryPage),
            "entryTitle": entry                                         
    })
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

**util.py**

```
def get_entry(title):
"""
Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
entry exists, the function returns None.
"""
try:
    f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
    return f.read().decode("utf-8")
except FileNotFoundError:
    return None
```

Comment: The function is missing an argument. Give it an argument. Meaning there is something missing inside those brackets ```markdown("Some Text must go here, assuming it is a string")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaleba said, try to change the line in your views.py to

`"entry": markdown(entryPage)`

Comment: It's really sad because the error info literally tells you what is wrong and in most cases if you just search for your error you'll get an answer. I don't know anything about Django but Im glad you were able to pinpoint the specific problem

Comment: Thank you @julianofischer and  Kaleba KB Keitshokile for your help. I eventually figured out what was wrong with the code later.:)

Comment: the server was running from the previous instance and therefore was not making any changes to my code. 

An Advice for beginners like me to restart the server after making changes to the code.